# WordArt for Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

OK... so I have a shiny new copy of Office 2013.  (AKA Office 365)

I set out today to make some WordArt in the shape of a pennat flag.

However, there is not option to change the shape of the WordArt in my copy of Office.

I did some reading...
Select WordArt object 
Then, under Drawing tools -> Shape Effects

There should be a Transform menu.

I seem to have all the other choices I have seen on other help sites

- Preset
- Shadow
- Reflection
- Glow
- Soft Edges
- Bevel
- 3D Rotation

But no transform.

I decided to try this another way... Insert WordArt object.  There is no WordArt object choice to choose from.

Does anybody have some insight into this?  It seems a feature is just missing.

I went to another computer with Office 2013... it has the WordArt / Transform option in the menu.

Sincerely yours,
Baffled

Comment: I have Word 2013 (Office 2013 Pro Plus), and I have no Transform menu there either. Aside from it being on that other computer you looked at, why do you expect that menu entry exists? What exactly are you trying to do when you say you want to "change the shape"? In what way(s) do you want to "change" it?

Comment: [Transform Tab not where it should be in Word Art](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/transform-tab-not-where-it-should-be-in-word-art/0b6c8d19-abb0-40fc-85b8-14f17beb93c6)

Comment: @DavidPostill Nice catch... I'm guessing that's what he saw on the other computer. But I _think_ what he's actually looking for the "Change Shape" command. :)

Answer (score 1):

David cracked it.  Thanks Dave.

[Transform Tab not where it should be in Word Art](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/transform-tab-not-where-it-should-be-in-word-art/0b6c8d19-abb0-40fc-85b8-14f17beb93c6) –  DavidPostill

In the future, I'll just check both locations.  :D

Answer (score 0):

On the **drawing Tools** tab, in the **Insert Shape** section is an *Edit Shape* button/dropdown, and under that is the *Change Shape* command:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  It's missing.  IN 2013, that menu only contains the Color and 3D text effects.

Comment: Exactly which version/edition of Office 2013/365 are you using?

Comment: @BAMF4bacon I redid my answer. Hopefully that's what you're looking for. :)